# Call signatures are incompatible within interfaces with params

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two interfaces: `IEvent` and `IWorkflowResizedEvent` that extends the first one.

```
interface IEvent {
    add?(listener: ()=> void): void;
    remove?(listener: ()=> void): void;
    trigger?(...a: any[]): void;
}

interface IWorkflowResizedEvent extends IEvent {
    add(listener:(args: WorkflowResizedEventArgs) => void): void;
    remove(listener:(args: WorkflowResizedEventArgs) => void ): void;
    trigger(args: WorkflowResizedEventArgs): void;
}

interface WorkflowResizedEventArgs {
}
```

I get an error:

> Interface 'IWorkflowResizedEvent cannot extend interface 'IEvent':
>   Types of property 'trigger' of types 'IWorkflowResizedEvent' and
>   'IEvent' are incompatible: Call signatures of types '(args:
>   WorkflowResizedEventArgs) => void' and '(...a: any()) => void' are
>   incompatible: Call signature expects 0 or fewer parameters.

I was using some old version of `TypeScript` library before and this piece of code was working well... Now I have updated the library to the newest one and the problems started. I found that whole language spec has changed so strongly...

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong in here? It looks like it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **TypeScript** `...`(so called *spread* operator) stands for something that we know from C# as a [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx). 
And according to new standards you'll have use the spread operator in the method call/override. That's why `IWorkflowResizedEvent` cannot extend `IEvent`.

Try this:

```
interface IEvent {
    add?(listener: ()=> void): void;
    remove?(listener: ()=> void): void;
    trigger?(...a: any[]): void;
}

interface IWorkflowResizedEvent extends IEvent {
    add(listener:(args: WorkflowResizedEventArgs) => void): void;
    remove(listener:(args: WorkflowResizedEventArgs) => void ): void;
    trigger(...args: WorkflowResizedEventArgs[]): void;
}

interface WorkflowResizedEventArgs {
}
```